# Matlab wrapToPi and python np.unwrap

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am trying to port my code from Matlab to Python.
Most of it seems to work except Matlab's function

```
wrapToPi
```

I am using numpy's unwrap function

```
np.unwrap
```

to mimic wrapToPi but it doesn't seem to work. On Matlab page, it says that

> lambdaWrapped = wrapToPi(lambda) wraps angles in lambda, in radians,
>   to the interval [−pi pi]. pi maps to pi and −pi maps to −pi. (In
>   general, odd, positive multiples of pi map to pi and odd, negative
>   multiples of pi map to −pi.)

How is wrapToPi different from np.unwrap?

Comment: Give some test cases where `unwrap` does not work as you expect.

Comment: A previous question that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664116/python-numpy-unwrap-function

Comment: np.unwrap is actually the *opposite* of MATLABs wrapToPi. wrapToPi will take values and wrap them into the range (-pi, pi]. np.unwrap will take wrapped values (such as the output of wrapToPi), and unwrap them so that there's no wraparound between consecutive values. For example, if your list contains consecutive values of pi, -pi/2, np.unwrap will change this to pi, 3pi/2. wrapToPi would then undo this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octave's `mapping` addon has this code:

```
function xwrap = wrapToPi(x)

  xwrap = rem (x, 2*pi);
  idx = find (abs (xwrap) > pi);
  xwrap(idx) -= 2*pi * sign (xwrap(idx));

endfunction
```

`unwrap` in `numpy` and `Octave` (and presumably MATLAB) is something entirely different.

```
>> x=linspace(-2*pi, 2*pi, 10)
x =
 Columns 1 through 8:
  -6.28319  -4.88692  -3.49066  -2.09440  -0.69813   0.69813   2.09440   3.49066
 Columns 9 and 10:
   4.88692   6.28319
>> wrapToPi(x)
ans =
 Columns 1 through 8:
   0.00000   1.39626   2.79253  -2.09440  -0.69813   0.69813   2.09440  -2.79253
 Columns 9 and 10:
  -1.39626   0.00000
```

In `numpy` I can replicate this with:

```
In [274]: x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 10)
In [275]: x
Out[275]: 
array([-6.28318531, -4.88692191, -3.4906585 , -2.0943951 , -0.6981317 ,
        0.6981317 ,  2.0943951 ,  3.4906585 ,  4.88692191,  6.28318531])
In [276]: xwrap=np.remainder(x, 2*np.pi)
In [277]: mask = np.abs(xwrap)>np.pi
In [278]: xwrap[mask] -= 2*np.pi * np.sign(xwrap[mask])
In [279]: xwrap
Out[279]: 
array([ 0.       ,  1.3962634,  2.7925268, -2.0943951, -0.6981317,
        0.6981317,  2.0943951, -2.7925268, -1.3962634,  0.       ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on hpaulj's answer, here we have a function which has exactly the same performance as Matlab. Just make sure your input is a numpy array

```
def wrapToPi(x):
    xwrap = np.remainder(x, 2 * np.pi)
    mask = np.abs(xwrap) > np.pi
    xwrap[mask] -= 2 * np.pi * np.sign(xwrap[mask])
    mask1 = x < 0
    mask2 = np.remainder(x, np.pi) == 0
    mask3 = np.remainder(x, 2 * np.pi) != 0
    xwrap[mask1 & mask2 & mask3] -= 2 * np.pi
    return xwrap
```